# Why does Conway define conformal maps in this way?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 46 the author defines conformal maps:

[image]

This makes me think why he didn't define conformal maps as usual, i.e., as a function with angle preserving property and that's all.

Comment: I think its just to avoid having to prove conformal maps are analytic and because only analytic functions really matter in the context of the book so nothing is lost.

Comment: On page 74 of Remmert's complex analysis text it is proved that real differentiable, orientation-preserving, angle-preserving maps are holomorphic with nonzero derivative.

Comment: I suppose the question you might ask is this: can you give an example of a angle preserving map which fails to be holomorphic. In some sense $f(z) = \bar{z}$ is an example, but, not if you insist on oriented angle-preservation.

Comment: @kaiten why does the existence of this limit avoid the author to prove the conformal maps are analytic?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook The definition of holomorphic functions in his book is given by $\lim_{x\to a}=\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}$ without modulus.

Comment: @user42912 indeed, so, what is the meaning of the given condition (the difference quotient with the modulus)? I think it may just be real differentiability.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook So, $f$ is real differentiable at a point $a$, now what? Thank you!